# MATLAB appdesigner chage selected cell in UItable

Tags: matlab, matlab-uitable, matlab-app-designer

I have a UItable in MATLAB appdesigner, let's say 'app.UITable'. Can I change the selected cell via callback function? For example, I would like to move one cell down when *Enter* key is pressed. For what I read, new MATLAB uiobjects do not accept button-press callbacks. Is that true? or is there any known hack to do that? Thank you.

Related [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42492289/buttondownfcn-with-matlab-appdesigner)

Answer (score 1):

As of R2018b, new figure interactions were added. Regarding your specific question, you should take a look at these new keyboard interaction callbacks:

- [`KeyPressFcn`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.ui.figure-properties.html#buiwuyk-1-KeyPressFcn) - *This callback function executes when the user presses a key while the figure or a child object has focus. If the user **presses** a key on a `UIControl` or `Table` component, the callback does not execute unless the `Enable` property is set to `'off'`.*
- [`KeyReleaseFcn`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.ui.figure-properties.html#buiwuyk-1-KeyReleaseFcn) - *This callback function executes when the user presses* [sic] *a key while the figure or a child object has focus. If the user **releases** a key on a `UIControl` or `Table` component, the callback does not execute unless the `Enable` property is set to `'off'`*.
- [`WindowKeyPressFcn`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.ui.figure-properties.html#buiwuyk-1-WindowKeyPressFcn) - *This callback function executes when the user presses a key while the figure or a child object has focus*.
- [`WindowKeyReleaseFcn`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.ui.figure-properties.html#buiwuyk-1-WindowKeyReleaseFcn) - *This callback function executes when the user releases a key while the figure or a child object has focus.*.

See also: [R2018 Release notes](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/release-notes.html?rntext=Figure+interactions&startrelease=R2018b&endrelease=R2018b&category=app-building&groupby=release&sortby=descending&search=Figure+interactions).